Best Websites for Mandarin Tutors
I'm looking for some advice on the best website to book lessons with a tutor. I've been learning Mandarin on Duolingo for about six months, but I feel like I need more personalized instruction now. I've found a few options, but I'm not sure which one to go with:
Preply
iTalki
Wise Panda
If you've used any of these, I'd love to hear about your experiences. Wise Panda seems to focus only on Mandarin tutors, while Preply and iTalki offer tutors for a variety of languages. There are so many choices out there, and these three are on my shortlist.
